# Trouble with jquery.getJSON prints as undefined or states the function is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

This is getting pretty frustrating and i thought this would be alot easier to do, all i'm trying to do is use a rails app i've created as an API, i couldn't seem to get it to work so i created a quick little test app to eliminate any thing that could really be complicated about it, I know very basic java script and my experience doesn't go much further then using Jquery for various effects ect.

I am using the rails-api gem, all I've done in this test is simply ran

```
Rails g scaffold user name
```

No views or anything like that has been created, when you navigate to the users path you will see a json array containing the users (currently the only fields would be created, updated, name and id)

Here's my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#new_user').submit(function(e) {
  $.post('/users', $(this).serialize());
  this.reset();
  e.preventDefault();
});

$.getJSON('/users', function(users) {
  $.each(users, function(user) { 
    var output = "<li>" + user.name + "</li>";
    $('#content ul').append(output);
 });
});

});
```

What the json that .getJson points to looks like

```
[{"user":{"created_at":"2013-01-23T02:30:42Z","id":1,"name":"test","updated_at":"2013-01-23T02:30:42Z"}},
{"user":{"created_at":"2013-01-23T02:31:49Z","id":2,"name":"test","updated_at":"2013-01-23T02:31:49Z"}}]
```

Posting works fine, but when when ran, the fields print Undefined, previously if i put user.user.name it would work just fine, obviously that doesn't seem like the best route though.

Is there something I'm missing or is this more complicated then i originally though, I figured all that would really be required to create an API client for my app would be to parse the json like i have here and simply output it to divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `user.user.name`.  `$.each` iterates over the array, but each has an object with the `user` key and the `name` key is inside that.

http://jsfiddle.net/DC5Gg/

Comment: Doesn't seem like a very clean way to do it though and every example I've read up on is doing the way I have this written, shouldn't I just be able to print Object.key? where user is the object and name is the key. I feel like the way i have this currently its attempting to run a function inside of my function, or am i confused?

Comment: Once you get to the JS level you no longer control how the JSON is constructed from the server.  Seems like a server-side problem.  I'm not a rails dev, though.

Comment: The Json seems to be formatted fairly normally, Rails shouldn't even really play into this anyways, it's just generating the json for me.

And if that's the case, then technically this should work shouldn't it? Since the format of the json is basically just

`{"user":{"name":"test"}}`

Comment: @charles.schlue the JSON object is `{"user:{"name":"test"}}`.  Say that this object is stored in a variable `user`, then you can get the `"test"` value with `user.user.name`.  If stored in a variable named `charles` it would be `charles.user.name`.  Do you see?

Comment: I suppose that makes sense, Right now i'm just using this.user.name since it atleast feels like i'm not repeating myself quite as much then, I guest the question here is, is there anyway to print this with out storing it in a variable? or just anyway to print the information by simply doing User.name? I ask because that' how you would generally print a user name or post using purely rails.

Comment: @charles.schlue I'm not sure, but you don't show any of your rails code either.  Perhaps you should accept this answer and ask another question specific to the rails problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23227/discussion-between-charles-schlue-and-explosion-pills)

Comment: Ended up just using this.object.key for the sake of not repeating myself, thank you for you help!